# Joining url path components intelligently

Tags: python, parsing, url

I'm a little frustrated with the state of url parsing in python, although I sympathize with the challenges. Today I just needed a tool to join path parts and normalize slashes without accidentally losing other parts of the URL, so I wrote this:

```
from urlparse import urlsplit, urlunsplit

def url_path_join(*parts):
    """Join and normalize url path parts with a slash."""
    schemes, netlocs, paths, queries, fragments = zip(*(urlsplit(part) for part in parts))
    # Use the first value for everything but path. Join the path on '/'
    scheme   = next((x for x in schemes if x), '')
    netloc   = next((x for x in netlocs if x), '')
    path     = '/'.join(x.strip('/') for x in paths if x)
    query    = next((x for x in queries if x), '')
    fragment = next((x for x in fragments if x), '')
    return urlunsplit((scheme, netloc, path, query, fragment))
```

As you can see, it's not very DRY, but it does do what I need, which is this:

```
>>> url_path_join('https://example.org/fizz', 'buzz')
'https://example.org/fizz/buzz'
```

Another example:

```
>>> parts=['https://', 'http://www.example.org', '?fuzz=buzz']
>>> '/'.join([x.strip('/') for x in parts]) # Not sufficient
'https:/http://www.example.org/?fuzz=buzz'
>>> url_path_join(*parts)
'https://www.example.org?fuzz=buzz'
```

Can you recommend an approach that is readable without being even more repetitive and verbose?

Comment: Why can't you just use `os.path.join` for taking care of the joining and such?

Comment: @Blender what if someone runs this code on Windows?

Comment: Could you please give more examples of the kind of input that would require your above code to accomplish? (i.e provide some test cases that should pass for the solution to be acceptable?). What about some thing simple such as `return '/'.join([x.strip('/') for x in parts])`

Comment: Sure, how about `parts=['https://', 'http://www.example.org', '?fuzz=buzz']`?

Comment: Just got burned by `urlparse.urljoin` today because it culls any existing paths on the first parameter.  _Who in the hell thought that was a great idea?_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest the following improvements (in descending order of importance):

1. Extract your redundant generator expression to a function so it only occurs *once*. To preserve flexibility, introduce `default` as an optional parameter
2. This makes the comment redundant because `first` is a self-documenting name (you could call it `first_or_default` if you want to be more explicit), so you can remove that
3. Rephrase your docstring to make it more readable: *normalize*  and *with a slash* don't make sense together
4. [PEP 8 suggests not to align variable assignments](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#pet-peeves), so does *Clean Code* by Robert C. Martin. However, it's more important to be consistent within your project.

---

```
def url_path_join(*parts):
    """Normalize url parts and join them with a slash."""
    schemes, netlocs, paths, queries, fragments = zip(*(urlsplit(part) for part in parts))
    scheme = first(schemes)
    netloc = first(netlocs)
    path = '/'.join(x.strip('/') for x in paths if x)
    query = first(queries)
    fragment = first(fragments)
    return urlunsplit((scheme, netloc, path, query, fragment))

def first(sequence, default=''):
    return next((x for x in sequence if x), default)
```

---

If you're looking for something a bit more radical in nature, why not let `first` handle several sequences at once? (Note that unfortunately, you cannot combine default parameters with sequence-unpacking in Python 2.7, which has been fixed in Python 3.)

```
def url_path_join(*parts):
    """Normalize url parts and join them with a slash."""
    schemes, netlocs, paths, queries, fragments = zip(*(urlsplit(part) for part in parts))
    scheme, netloc, query, fragment = first_of_each(schemes, netlocs, queries, fragments)
    path = '/'.join(x.strip('/') for x in paths if x)
    return urlunsplit((scheme, netloc, path, query, fragment))

def first_of_each(*sequences):
    return (next((x for x in sequence if x), '') for sequence in sequences)
```

Answer (score -2):

I fully agree with Blender. Just use the os.path module. It provides a method to join paths and it also has methods to normalize pathnames (eg. os.path.normpath(pathname)) to use it on every OS with different separators.

Comment: `os.path.normpath` does not use forward slashes on Windows by default, and it's not intelligent about keeping the double slashes after `http://`.

Comment: @kojiro Yes, but you can `import posixpath` instead of `import os.path` to get the correct slashes. I do believe you are correct about the `http://` though